# pacing code execution in a Unity based Roguelike

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

[UPDATE] I tried using the suggestion below but am still having an issue where the enemies appear to move simultaneously and they each move twice when first seen if there is already an enemy in line of sight. All I really want to do is have a delay between the actions of enemies in the player s line of sight so they do not simultaneously move, play sounds etc...

The updated code is:

```
    private IEnumerator takeAllEnemyActions()
{
    // Cycle through all enemies and have them perform their actions
    if (Enemies != null && Enemies.Length > 0)
    {
        bool foundEnemyInLoS = false;
        Enemy lastEnemy = null;
        foreach (GameObject enemy in Enemies)
        {
            // Cache the enemies script
            Enemy thisEnemy = enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>();

            // If it is not this enemies turn to move then move on to the next enemy
            if (thisEnemy.NextMoveTick > GameManager.Instance.CurrentTick)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Check to see is this enemy is the first enemy in the players line of sight (If there is one)
            if (!foundEnemyInLoS && thisEnemy.isInLineOfSightOfPlayer())
            {
                // If so then we save it for last to ensure that if any enemy is called with a delay that the last one does not make the player wait to move
                foundEnemyInLoS = true;
                lastEnemy = thisEnemy;
                continue;
            }

            // At this point only enemies whose turn it is and who are not being saved for later can act
            thisEnemy.TakeEnemyActions();

            // If the enemy was in the players line of sight wait 200ms before continuing
            if (thisEnemy.isInLineOfSightOfPlayer())
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
            }
        }

        // if there were enemies in the players line of sight then one was saved for last
        // Take its action without a delay so the player can go next
        if (foundEnemyInLoS)
        {
            lastEnemy.TakeEnemyActions();
        }
    }
```

Original Question:
In a top down, 2d, turn based roguelike in Unity3d 5 I am having an issue with game pacing. I am using a very simple state machine to control execution but I want enemies that all move in the same turn to do so with a pause between each one if they are in the players line of sight so that animations and sound have time to occur without overlapping (Especially sounds). The only issue I am having is getting the actual pause to occur without affecting animations or camera movement (The camera may be sliding to follow a player movement and it was stopping). I only need about a 100ms pause before moving to the next enemy.

The enemies are taking their actions in a foreach loop in an EnemyManager script

```
private void takeAllEnemyActions()
{
    // Cycle through all enemies and have them perform their actions
    if (Enemies != null && Enemies.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (GameObject enemy in Enemies)
            if (enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().NextMoveTick <= GameManager.Instance.CurrentTick)
                enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeEnemyActions();
    }
    GameManager.States.NextPlayState();
}
```

I tried creating a routine to invoke each enemy to act but the issue there was that execution of other enemies continued.

I tried using a coroutine but again the issue was the game would move on into the next state.

I even tried a while-do loop using Time.RealTimeSinceStartup just to see what it would do (I know, a very VERY bad idea)

I'm certain this is simple and I am just having a brain cramp but I've been trying things and google-binging for hours with no progress. Thank goddness for git to roll back.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to go? I'm not needing someone to write my code, I just need pointed in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, there's a [dedicated SO site for game development](gamedev.stackexchange.com). For future questions, you'll probably get a better answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Use a co-routine and yield for each statement. Here's some modified code.

```
private IEnumerator TakeAllEnemyActions() {
    // Cycle through all enemies and have them perform their actions
    if (enemies != null && enemies.Length > 0) {
        foreach (var enemy in enemies) {
            if (enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().NextMoveTick <= GameManager.Instance.CurrentTick) {
                enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeEnemyActions();
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f);
            }
        } 
    }
    GameManager.States.NextPlayState();
}
```

Call this method with

```
 StartCoroutine(TakeAllEnemyActions());
```

Comment: Ok this is working better except (and its a big except) it is getting to the NextPlayState so you get stuck in a loop where the enemies act but they no longer wait for the player on their turn. I'm going to look into this further this evening. Perhaps I need to rethink this a bit

Comment: OK I have been working on this but am still having issues. I updated the main question